# Download all attachments from HP ALM Test Plan

Tags: vbscript, hp-alm

I need to download all the attachments from all the tests within the test plan. I have a function that should do that and I need some advice with it.

I have posted the function that I have used to get all the attachments. I have tried retrieving the attachments based on a path that is given.
I have tried changing the filter based on values I have found in the  CROS_REF table, CR_REFERENCE field.

```
Public Function DownloadAttachments(TDFolderPath, sDownloadTo)
Dim otaAttachmentFactory 'As TDAPIOLELib.AttachmentFactory
Dim otaAttachment 'As TDAPIOLELib.Attachment
Dim otaAttachmentList 'As TDAPIOLELib.List
Dim otaAttachmentFilter 'As TDAPIOLELib.TDFilter
Dim otaTreeManager 'As TDAPIOLELib.TreeManager
Dim otaSysTreeNode 'As TDAPIOLELib.SysTreeNode
Dim otaExtendedStorage 'As TDAPIOLELib.TreeManager
Dim fso

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim strPath 'As String
Set otaTreeManager = QCUtil.TDConnection.TreeManager
Set otaSysTreeNode = otaTreeManager.NodeByPath(TDFolderPath)
Set otaAttachmentFactory = otaSysTreeNode.Attachments

Set otaAttachmentFilter = otaAttachmentFactory.Filter
otaAttachmentFilter.Filter("CR_REFERENCE") = "'ALL_LISTS_" & otaSysTreeNode.NodeID & "_*'"

Set otaAttachmentList = otaAttachmentFilter.NewList
DowloadAttachments = ""

If otaAttachmentList.Count > 0 Then
For i = 1 to otaAttachmentList.Count
set otaAttachment = otaAttachmentList.Item(i)
otaAttachment.Load True, ""
If (fso.FileExists(otaAttachment.FileName)) Then
strFile = otaAttachmentList.Item(i).Name
myarray = split(strFile,"ALL_LISTS_"& otaSysTreeNode.NodeID & "_")
fso.CopyFile otaAttachment.FileName, sDownloadTo & "\" & myarray(1)
Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "File Download:", myarray(1) & " downloaded to " & sDownloadTo
DownloadAttachments = sDownloadTo
end if
Next
Else
Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "No attachments to download", _
"No attachments found in specified folder '" & TDFolderPath & "'."
DowloadAttachments = "Empty"
End If
Set otaAttachmentFactory = Nothing
Set otaAttachment = Nothing
Set otaAttachmentList = Nothing
Set otaAttachmentFilter = Nothing
Set otaTreeManager = Nothing
Set otaSysTreeNode = Nothing
Set fso = nothing
End Function
```

Regardless of what (valid) path I have tried, the result is the same. It says that there are no attachments to download.
I`m pretty sure the issue is in this piece of code:

```
Set otaAttachmentFilter = otaAttachmentFactory.Filter
otaAttachmentFilter.Filter("CR_REFERENCE") = "'ALL_LISTS_" & otaSysTreeNode.NodeID & "_*'"
```

Also, if anyone has any advice over other approaches, any help would be gladly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
otaAttachmentFilter.Filter("CR_Reference") = "'ALL_LISTS_" & otaSysTreeNode.NodeID & _"_" & sDownloadTo & "'"
```

Check this solution out. It might work.

Comment: Hi Vishnu, welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for answering this question. Some additional explanation about why your solutions would work will greatly enhance your answer so others can learn from it too. =)